# NSDictionary in NSArray Malfunction

Tags: objective-c, ios

Ok my code is returning the array. My log for JSONArray bellow returns perfectly so I dont see why the dictionary is  giving insane results posted below this code:

```
NSMutableArray *listOfparts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *object in JSONArray) {
        Part *part = [[Part alloc] initWithpartName:object[@"case_name"]
                imageName:object[@"case_image"]];
        [listOfparts addObject:part];

    }
    NSLog(@"array: %@", JSONArray);
```

// Log for JSONArray - Looks nice //

```
array: (
        {
        "case_color" = White;
        "case_description" = "";
        "case_image" = "";
        "case_name" = "NZXT Phantom 410";
        "case_price" = "99.99";
        "case_type" = ATX;
        id = 1;
    },
        {
        "case_color" = Black;
        "case_description" = "";
        "case_image" = "";
        "case_name" = "Thermaltake MK+";
        "case_price" = "84.99";
        "case_type" = ATX;
        id = 2;
    }
)
```

// Log for listOfparts - Doesnt look good //

```
array: (
    "<Part: 0x71b5530>",
    "<Part: 0x71b5640>"
)
```

any help would be appreciated!

Update: I dont think my table is getting it right then

```
Part *eachpart = [listOfparts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.label.text = eachpart.part_name;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:eachpart.part_image];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `Parts` which I think are classes made by you (like an `UIButton` or `UIView`), do these classes have properties like `partName` or `imageName`? Print those instead.

Btw, your code seems to be working fine :)

Comment: Your right. I printed them and they returned ok but for my table I dont see a thing. Check my update.

Comment: Access the cell's text like this `cell.textLabel.text`

Comment: Also, try using the accessoryView for your image (as an UIImageView), see how that works out for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the values shown on the console, you are only seeing the memory address of those objects. This is the default behavior. If you want the console to show the values of your properties, just subclass the - (NSString *)description method of your NSObject subclass(in this case, Part), and return a string that has a format with the property values you would like to see on the console.

Comment: Yeah, it's often worthwhile to spend a little time writing `description` methods for your most-used classes.